# Calling a function, and then sending a key in neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

```
map z. <Cmd>call repeat(VSCodeNotify('editor.action.commentLine')j, v:count1)<CR>
```

The idea is to call the [vscode command](https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim#invoking-vscode-actions-from-neovim) for commenting, and then the down key. With that, if I pass `5z.`, the next 5 lines get commented out

This code doesn't work. Does work if I remove `j` (but with that, I don't get the wanted behavior)

The repeat command also doesn't work. you'd expect the comment function to cancel out if you call it twice (it's a "toggle comment" function), but it only executes once, no matter what number I input

Comment: Seems that you are using vscode-neovim, it can use all nvim plugins, no need to reinvent the wheel. Just use https://github.com/numToStr/Comment.nvim.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Yeah, it makes sense to do that, it's just that I already have support for comments in vscode, and vim might not have them for my language (autohotkey). However, turns out that the neovim extension already has a hotkey for commenting smartly (<C-/>) when in visual mode, so hell yeah!